# UILabel subview in UITableViewCell isn't showing up. (iPhone Dev)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a cell in a table view that has a UILabel as a subview, when I set the text of the label, it is never shown on the cell. I'm somewhat a noob in iPhone development and am not sure what I'm doing wrong...

**I am creating and returning the following cell in my table view's cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate:**

```
cell = [[[ActivityCell alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:ColumnedCell] autorelease];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(180.0, 11.0, 130.0, 22);

UILabel *valueField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[valueField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
valueField.tag = 111;
valueField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
valueField.textColor = [UIColor colorFromHex:@"326799"];
valueField.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
valueField.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
valueField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

[cell.contentView addSubview:valueField];
[valueField release];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

**I then want to set the UILabel (subview) later by doing this (I currently have this code in viewDidAppear):**

```
ActivityCell *cell = (ActivityCell*)[formDetailsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];

UITextField *valueField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:111];
valueField.text = @"foo";
```

But the word "foo" never shows up in the UILabel. I believe it shows up when I compile with <= 2.2 SDK, but I want to get this working with 3.0+

Any ideas of why the text isn't showing up?

**FOLLOW UP:**

Please take a look at this question as a follow up to this: [UITableViewCell's textLabel is overlapping a subview label, how can I fix it? (iPhone Dev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981260/uitableviewcells-textlabel-is-overlapping-a-subview-label-how-can-i-fix-it-i)

Answer (score 2):

Well first off, you're creating a UILabel, tagging it as 111, and then adding it as a subview  to the cell's contentView. Later on, you are trying to retrieve that UILabel but you're casting it to a UITextField. Fundamentally something you're doing here is wrong.

Here's what I recommend doing:

1. Take a look at Apple's guide for [using Interface Builder to create cells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20). It's going to lead to a lot less code and you'll be able to easily see what's going on, and won't have to add the Label/TextField programatically.
2. Instead of trying to access cells directly in viewDidAppear and changing their subviews, you should be doing all of that display logic inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In another method (for example, one called when the user touches a button), you'll modify some data structure and then send the tableView the `reloadData` message. At that time, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called again and the values set in your data structure determines how the cell is created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a small bug:

change

```
UITextField *valueField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:111];
```

to

```
UITextField *valueField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
```

Comment: No luck, the valueField.text looks like it's set (via NSLog) but It doesn't show up in the view.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the cell coming back is nil and thus not updating your text.  I would start buy making sure you are getting a cell back from this line:

```
ActivityCell *cell = (ActivityCell*)[formDetailsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cell = [[[ActivityCell alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:ColumnedCell] autorelease];
```

your cell has a frame of CGRectZero

Comment: The frame a table-view cell is initialized with is typically irrelevant, as the UITableView manages that along with a number of other aspects of the cell. This is probably why the designated initializer for `UITableViewCell`—`-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`—now eliminates the "frame" parameter entirely.