# UITableViewCell's textLabel is overlapping a subview label, how can I fix it? (iPhone Dev)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

As a follow up to: [UILabel subview in UITableViewCell isn't showing up. (iPhone Dev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971165/uilabel-subview-in-uitableviewcell-isnt-showing-up-iphone-dev)

I have found out that the UILabel I added as a subview is showing up and positioned correctly, however when I set the cell's labelField, it seems to "overlap" the label I have added in the subview.

In other words "bar" only shows up when I comment out the first line of the following code snippet:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"foo"
// sub view text label
UILabel *valueField = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:111];
valueField.text = @"bar";
```

Is there a way to make the cell.textLabel not overlap the UILabel that's on the "same line"? maybe by adjusting the underlying frame of cell.textLabel?

This problem also seems to only occur when I'm compiling with an SDK > 2.2.1, did something change that would affect this in 3.0?

Thanks

Comment: Would love to know why the down vote...

Comment: Why are you placing a label as a subview of the cell when the cell already has a label you can use? I don't understand. Either use the one that provided as part of the default cell layout or change the position of the label you add...?

Comment: I want to have the default label aligned left, with another label aligned to the right of the cell row to hold some meta information, should be fairly simple...

Comment: which sdk you are using if it is 3.0 or above use uitableviewcellstylevalue2.This has by default two labels you can set text like this cell.textlabel.text and cell.detailtextlabel.text.
if it is 2.0 then may be your label's frame is issue

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell´s textLabel has a non clear background. I think that the position from your custom label to this one is so tiny that when the default textLabel shows text, it´s background covers your custom label (bar).

Change the background color for the default textLabel field in this message:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```